# Swype keyboard turns into a black area

Tags: keyboard, swype, input-methods, samsung-galaxy-note

Every day or two,  my swype keyboard turns into a black area. There are no keys or anything. Just a black area, and I have to change input mode to samsung keyboard and then back to Swype to get it working again. This is really annoying . any one else had the same issue ?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Note (Android version: 2.3.6, N7000XXLA4) that came with Swype pre-loaded.

Comment: Could be related to the Note's larger screen resolution.  How did you install Swype?  Did you side-load it manually (from your older phone perhaps) or via Swype Installer from http://beta.swype.com/android/get the normal way?  Do you have the latest version of the beta?  Have you tried completely un-installing Swype and re-installing it?

Comment: It had swype pre-installed. Earlier i was using galaxy s and it too had swype. I have never installed swype from beta.swype.com

Comment: If it came pre-loaded, you may not be able to upgrade it to latest version unless you root the Note and get rid of the (possibly old and buggy) pre-installed version.

Comment: Ok. thanks for that. I think I shall wait for the ICS update then :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a symptom of the Swype application data becoming corrupted following a hardware upgrade.

To resolve this, go into Settings > Manage Applications > All > Swype and clear the application data. Then force the Swype service to restart.

Comment: hi lisa, thanks for your answer. Yes i did that and used it a couple of times,. havent seen the issue yet. Will see if it crops up again for a  couple of days,. if not i will accept your answer. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I am having this same problem on my HTC thunderbolt. The way to fix it is to go into settings - applications and then stop the swype application. After you can set your keyboard to swype again and it will work. There is probably a bug in the newest version.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I do as well. Its very annoying as it happens very often now. I am so waiting for the ICS update.

Answer (score 1):

In Motorola Atrix 2, when swype keyboards freezes, I simply keep pressing on the keyboard area, so a popup notice tells the aplication will force closure. That is a quick way to make the keyboard restart and work.